# Matching a fixed point with an interval in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm trying to match stock trades from one data frame with the mid-quote that was prevailing during that time. Thus, the time stamps don't match exactly but I have just a corresponding time interval of quotes for the time the trade happened.
I wrote a loop which works but since I know that loops should be avoided whenever possible, I looked out for an alternative.
First, this is my loop:

> ```
> t=dim(x1)[1]
> z=1  
> for (i in 1:t) {  
>  flag=FALSE  
>  while(flag==FALSE){  
>   if(x1[z,1]>x2[i,1]){    
>    x2[i,2]=x1[z-1,2]  
>    flag=TRUE  
>    }  
>   else {  
>   z=z+1         
>   }  
>  }  
> }
> ```

I've found the advice on Stack Overflow to merge the two arrays, so I added the upper bound of the interval as another column and matched the corresponding times with the subset-function.
Unfortunately, this method takes far more time than the loop. I assume it's due to the huge array that is created by merging. The data frames with the quotes have like 500.000 observations and the transaction data 100.000.
Is there a more elegant (and especially faster) way to solve this problem?
Furthermore, for some data I get the error message "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", even though the if-condition works when I do it manually.

edit:
My quote data would look like this:

> ```
>         Time   midquote
>
>     [1,] 35551   50.85229  
>     [2,] 35589   53.77627  
>     [3,] 36347   54.27945  
>     [4,] 37460   52.01283  
>     [5,] 37739   53.65414  
>     [6,] 38249   52.34947    
>     [7,] 38426   50.59568  
>     [8,] 39858   53.75646  
>     [9,] 40219   51.38876  
>    [10,] 40915   52.09319
> ```

and my transaction data:

> ```
>          Time   midquote
>    [1,] 36429        0  
>    [2,] 38966        0  
>    [3,] 39334        0  
>    [4,] 39998        0  
>    [5,] 40831        0
> ```

So I want to know the midquotes from the time in the latter from the corresponding time of the former. The time in the example is in seconds from midnight.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: I've edited the question and added an example

Comment: Thanks for the examples. What is `x1`, what is `x2`, what is `t`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot: x1 is the quote data, x2 the transaction data. T is the number of observations in the latter ( I specify it as t= dim(x2)[1])

Comment: I think I've made a mistake there. The if condition should be `x1[z,1]>x2[i,1]` and the replacement `x2[i,2]=x1[z-1,2]`
Still, I wonder how one could do that more efficiently in R

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example datasets, the following approach is faster:

```
x2[ , 2] <- x1[vapply(x2[, 1], function(x) which(x <= x1[, 1])[1] - 1L, 
                      FUN.VALUE = integer(1)), 2]

#       Time midquote
# [1,] 36429 54.27945
# [2,] 38966 50.59568
# [3,] 39334 50.59568
# [4,] 39998 53.75646
# [5,] 40831 51.38876
```

---

A second approach:

```
o <- order(c(x1[ , 1], x2[ , 1]))
tmp <- c(x1[ , 2], x2[ , 2])[o]
idx <- which(!tmp)
x2[ , 2] <- tmp[unlist(tapply(idx, c(0, cumsum(diff(idx) > 1)), 
                              function(x) x - seq_along(x)), use.names = FALSE)]

#       Time midquote
# [1,] 36429 54.27945
# [2,] 38966 50.59568
# [3,] 39334 50.59568
# [4,] 39998 53.75646
# [5,] 40831 51.38876
```

Comment: great, thank you very much. I would vote up if I had the reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply it to longer (randomly time series, your code takes much longer. For exmaple 2000 observations in x1 and 1000 in x2:
`Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 original() 17.93335 26.32057 30.66450 31.68612  41.5735   100
      new() 54.19432 69.49856 73.32077 77.32665 127.2299   100
`

Comment: @Arne See the update. Hopefully, the second approach is faster for the larger dataset.